# Is this a feasible way to determine if a port can be used by a server for Http or Ws?

Tags: c#, sockets, http, websocket

I'm developing an application that hosts a browser control. The client (in the browser, using a localhost address) communicates with the server via websockets and the server handles the Http requests.

The users can define ports for both Http and Ws, but (since several instances of the application can be opened) I need to detect, if they are usable - if not, I notify the users that an alternative port will be used.

Verifying that the intended Http port is blocked was possible using a `HttpListener`, but (for reasons I don't understand) the listener could apparently use a port already used by another application for a websocket connection.

So I ended up with the following code, which appears to do the job. I use it to first test a specified port and, if that fails, I loop through a range of port numbers and try until the method returns `True`.

```
private static bool testPort(int port)
{
    bool result = false;

    System.Net.IPEndPoint endpoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Loopback, port);

    using (System.Net.Sockets.Socket s = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP)) {
        try {
            Console.WriteLine("Testing port {0}", port);

            s.Connect(endpoint);
            s.Bind(endpoint);

            result = true;
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            switch (ex.SocketErrorCode) {
                case SocketError.InvalidArgument:
                    //This error is apparently thrown when a port is occupied.
                    result = false;

                    break;
                case SocketError.ConnectionRefused:
                    //NOTE: This error is apparently thrown when a port is not occupied (but the connection fails, because the socket cannot connect since the port is not being used?).
                    result = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    result = false;
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            result = false;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

But I'm not sure, if maybe it's just a "lucky coincidence". Like I mentioned, it works as far as I could test it, but does it make any sense? And: is it reliable?

Answer (score 0):

The code is subject to a race condition.  The connect call might fail because the port is not in use, but another program may then take that port before the function is able to return.

Testing a bunch of ports could result in noticeable delays as well.  For example a firewall may be configured to drop packets rather than sending a connection refused response.  In this case the connect call would block until a timeout is reached.

As a side note, `Bind` needs to be called before `Connect` to work, however in this case the `Bind` call should be removed. You cannot bind a connecting socket to the same endpoint you're attempting to connect to.

Comment: thanks for your comments! i'm aware of the race condition, but the "gap" left is fine for my purposes. i'll have to check the behavior after changing `Connect` and `Bind`; it was a tiresome trial&error process, I hope the strangeness of my code logic has a better explanation than me just being totally annoyed ;o)

Comment: @mike `Bind` is used to set the local endpoint of a socket.  For a `Connect`ing socket, this allows you to connect from a specific IP and port if the machine has multiple.  For a `Listen`ing socket, this sets the IP/Port on which connections are received.